# how to append php with script variable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to append php code and I want to use script varible in my php code.
How can i do this?

```js
function sendajax(id,status,count){
    $.ajax({
    url : '{{url("admin/loadmoredata")}}',
    method : "POST",
    data : {id:id,status:status,count:count, _token:"{{csrf_token()}}"},
    dataType : "json",
    success : function (data)
    {

    if(status = 1) 
    {
        if(data[0] == 400){
            $('.acceptorder-btn').html('no data');
        }else{
            console.log(data[2])
            var row = data[1];
            $.each(data[2], function( index, value ) {
                row++           
               $('.load').append(`<tr> <td> `+row+` </td> <td> <?php $vlue = `+value["id"]+` ; dd($vlue); ?></td> <td>`+value["receiver_name"]+`</td></tr>` );
               $('#btn-more').removeAttr('data-id');
               $('.loadmore-btn').attr('data-id',value['id']);
            });
        }
        // $('.load').append(data);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#btn-more").html("No Data");
    }

    }

    });
}

});
```

I can show script variable like this `echo '+value["id"]+'`
but I can't use this for variable in php and when I `dd()` variable it returns null.

Comment: What do you trying to do? I think it's better explain, maybe you went a wrong way! I don't understand, why you use php variable like that!